# Applet flickering

Tags: java, applet

I know a lot of people had the same problem as me, but I can't seem to able to fix my applet looking at their solutions. I should probably use JApplet, JFrames and JPanel to do this project but I want to do a project first with Applet before I move on to using Japplet(I want to see the difference between those two). Could someone please look at my paint method and see why it flickers? Can't seem to be able to double buffer it.

```
    import java.applet.*;

    import java.awt.*;

    import java.awt.event.*;


    import java.net.*;

public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {
    private Ninja ninja;
    private Image character;
    private URL base;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(800, 480);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setFocusable(true);

        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("NinjaGirl");
        addKeyListener(this);
        try {
            base = getDocumentBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        character = getImage(base, "data/FrontStanding.png");
        super.init();

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        ninja = new Ninja();
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        super.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        super.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        super.update(g);


    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {


        g.drawImage(character, ninja.getCenterX(), ninja.getCenterY(), this);



    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ninja.update();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            ninja.moveUp();
            System.out.println("Up key pressed");

            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            ninja.moveDown();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            ninja.moveRight();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            ninja.moveLeft();
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            ninja.stop();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            ninja.stop();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            ninja.stop();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            ninja.stop();
            break;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

}
```

Comment: `Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();` is a bad idea.  `Applets` typically live in a browser, to which, you won't be allowed to get direct access to...

Comment: *"but I want to do a project first with Applet before I move on to using Japplet"*  There is no profit to be had by learning AWT fist.  Use `JApplet`.  But why code an applet at all?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1):

You're primary problem is here...

```
@Override
public void update(Graphics g) {
    super.update(g);
}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(character, ninja.getCenterX(), ninja.getCenterY(), this);
}
```

`Applet` (and all top level containers) is not double buffered, this means, you are drawing directly onto the screen device.  Some of the these functions can be slow (flood fill for example) which, if done fast enough, can cause flickering.

Instead, you need to implement your own double buffering process

```
@Override
public void update(Graphics g) {
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), Transparency.OPAQUE);
    Graphics2D g2d = image.getGraphics();
    super.update(g2d);
    g2d.dispose();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(character, ninja.getCenterX(), ninja.getCenterY(), this);
}
```

Now, having said that, Applet is over 15 years out of date and was replaced with `JApplet` and the Swing API.

Instead, you should start creating your UI on something like a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and do your custom painting there.

Swing components are double buffered by default, so you don't need to go to the extra trouble...unless you really, really want to

You can then add this to whatever top level container you like `JFrame`, `JWindow`, `JDialog`, `JApplet`

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: I was in the middle of posting the exact same answer...
I got ninjad.

I would also like to add on top of his answer that is not the best practice to override methods that are then left unused or that just make a call to its parent.

the methods stop, destroy, and update do not need to be listed at all.

Comment: Yeah, my mad typing skills...including spelling mistakes, bad grammar and generally illegality...:P

Comment: you can improve on this by moving the creation of the bufferedImage out of update and only create it once at the beginning and every time the window changes size.  But using a JPanel is much better.

Comment: Yeah, an applets not likely to change size that often

Comment: Holy that doublebuffer looks complicated ._. Thanks for the awesome explanation!
I guess I should just skip applets and move on to using JApplets. 

I tried to follow what you said. Basically I created a class and extended JApplet to it. Then in the init() method I created a JPanel object called jp and added it to my JApplet by writing this.add(jp)

Is this correct? Where does the Jframe come in?

Whole code if you're interested-
`

Comment: I followed your code, @MadProgrammer and managed to make my own version and it stopped the flickering! :D


`
@Override
 public void update(Graphics g) {
  
  image = createImage(this.getWidth(), getHeight());
  second = image.getGraphics();
  
  super.update(second);
  second.dispose();
  g.drawImage(image, 0,0,this);

 }

`

Comment: Applets are intended to be displayed in browsers, frames are your normal every day windows. Applets run in there own security sand box, which can limit what you can do with them